# Mongo aggregation: Sort stage after lookup and unwind too slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that has about 30 attributes 2 of which are relationships (ObjectId) to 2 other collections. I need to be able to sort the parent collection by columns of the 2 children collections.

To do this, I've written a pipeline that goes like this:

```
 Document.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      deleted: false,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup:
    {
      from: 'companies',
      localField: 'company',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'company',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind:
    {
      path: '$company',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup:
    {
      from: 'suppliers',
      localField: 'supplier',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'supplier',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind:
    {
      path: '$supplier',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: { 'company.name': -1 },
  },
  {
    $skip: 0,
  },
  {
    $limit: 10,
  }
]);
```

The problem is that this is too slow. In Compass it exceeds the time limit and when I run it in node it takes about 10 seconds to process. The size of the parent collection is around 60k. Without the sort stage, it runs for about 25ms. Also, when I move the sort stage at the top of the pipeline, it runs very fast but the results are not correct if I want to sort by the 'company.name' attribute. The 'company' and 'supplier' attributes in the parent collection are both indexed.

I've read that in order for the sort stage to make use of indexes, it needs to be put in the beginning of the pipeline along with the 'match' stage, but that does not fulfil my requirement of sorting by an attribute of the child collection. Is it impossible to make this run in less than 100ms? What am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

Here is the explain:

```
{ stages:
   [ { '$cursor':
        { query: { state: true },
          queryPlanner:
           { plannerVersion: 1,
             namespace: 'test.documents',
             indexFilterSet: false,
             parsedQuery: { state: { '$eq': true } },
             winningPlan:
              { stage: 'FETCH',
                inputStage:
                 { stage: 'IXSCAN',
                   keyPattern: { state: 1 },
                   indexName: 'state_1',
                   isMultiKey: false,
                   multiKeyPaths: { state: [] },
                   isUnique: false,
                   isSparse: false,
                   isPartial: false,
                   indexVersion: 2,
                   direction: 'forward',
                   indexBounds: { state: [ '[true, true]' ] } } },
             rejectedPlans: [] } } },
     { '$lookup':
        { from: 'companies',
          as: 'company',
          localField: 'company',
          foreignField: '_id',
          unwinding: { preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } } },
     { '$lookup':
        { from: 'suppliers',
          as: 'supplier',
          localField: 'supplier',
          foreignField: '_id',
          unwinding: { preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } } },
     { '$sort': { sortKey: { 'company.name': -1 }, limit: 10 } } ],
  ok: 1 }
```

In the document collection, the `company`, `supplier`, `state` fields are all indexes.

Comment: How about you start with `companies` so that you can sort & match, and then `$lookup` `Documents` to do the `deleted` filtering?

Comment: @willis: This is a dynamic searching/filtering for a data table in the frontend. There might be many filters/sorts etc. The collection that contains the most data is the big one (60k entries). If I start from `companies`, it wouldn't feel like a permanent/optimal solution and I'm almost sure there will be problems with other things.

Comment: OK, so that initial `$match` might be more complicated than shown, right? I don't know the aggregation pipeline well enough to know if there's a solution there, but you could try breaking out `Document $match` from the rest of the pipeline so that you can $match, and $sort by companies. Someone else might be able to give better advice if you share some `explain` output & your current indexes.

Comment: @willis Updated question! Thanks

Comment: @Arlind did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Answer from this link is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036938/mongodb-sort-is-slow-with-lookup-collections

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem of the timeout, what I did in that scenario and it worked for me was to project the lookup objects as such:
like in our case example the company.name:
@project: { name = $company.name }
now do the sorting on this name attribute and it will not show an error. which is strange, even it should work on the lookup object directly but still this worked for me.