# Why MongoDb sort is slow with lookup collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in my mongodb database as follows:

> ***employee_details*** with approximately 330000 documents which has *department_id* as a reference from departments collection
>
> ***departments*** collections with 2 fields *_id* and *dept_name*

I want to join the above two collections using department_id as foreign key by using lookup method. Join works fine but the mongo query execution takes long time when I add sort.

> Note: The execution is fast If I remove the sort object or If I remove the lookup method.

I have referred several posts in different blogs and SO, but none of them give a solution with sort.

My query is given below:

```
db.getCollection("employee_details").aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "departments",
      localField: "department_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "Department"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: { path: "$Department", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $sort: { employee_fname: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 }
]);
```

Can someone give a method to make the above query to work without delay, as my client cannot compromise with the performance delay. I hope there is some method to fix the performance issue as nosql is intented to handle large database.

Any indexing methods is available there? so that I can use it along with my same collection structure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `employee_fname` is the key from `employee_details` collection then create an index on it. And also use the `$sort` and `$limit` stage before the `$lookup`.

Comment: @Ashh can you post as answer please, also let me know does your suggestion works for sort with `dept_name` also?

Comment: It will work for whatever the fields you have in `employee_details` collection. Just use an index.

Comment: @Ashh Can you help me out for adding index for fields to my `employee_details` collections ? As I mentioned in the question. I dont know how to add index for improving performance

Comment: You can check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) to learn how to create an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently lookup will be made for every employee_details which means for 330000 times, but if we first sort and limit before lookup, it will be only 10 times. This will greatly decrease query time.

```js
db.getCollection('employee_details').aggregate([
    {$sort      : {employee_fname: -1}},
    {$limit     :10},
    {
        $lookup : {
            from         : "departments",
            localField   : "department_id",
            foreignField : "_id",
            as           : "Department"
        }
    },
    { $unwind   : { path: "$Department", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
])
```

After trying this, if you even want to decrease the response time you can define an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) on the sort field.

```js
db.employee_details.createIndex( { employee_fname: -1 } )
```

Comment: @sah  Good solution, One more doubt, Is it possible to sort according to dept_name

Comment: @Ajith yes it is possible, but we need to first lookup, and then sort and limit, which will make the query slower, but creating an index on dept_name might help.

Comment: @Sah But even after adding dept_name to index, query is slower. So if we bring sort after lookup, query is always slower irrespective of createIndex. Any other optimised solution . I hope you understood what I mean .. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ajith then we need to improve lookup, I think creating an index on employee_details deparment_id may help, can you try please?  `db.employee_details.createIndex( { department_id: 1 } )`

Comment: @Sah createIndex for department_id is possible but , How can I sort based on dept_name , I cannot add it above lookup , also I need match also , that too cannot add above lookup. The only problem exist is for joined collections(sort and match).  Things will work if I add below lookup but it takes around 1 minutes for query(which I cannot do)

Comment: @Ajith can you check the updated answer? Sorting by `Department.dept_name` will be sure slower than sorting by employee_details.employee_fname. Because we need to first lookup, sort and limit.

Comment: @Sah I tried your edit, but the query execution takes long time to complete :( my issue didnt solved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207157/discussion-between-ajith-and-suleymansah).

Comment: @Ajith what happened? I didn't notice what you wrote to me in the chat.